# Casting from interface vs from parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Given the class

```
public class Dog extends Animal implements Friend{

  ...
}
```

Which of the following is more expensive performance wise?

```
Dog myDog = (Dog) someAnimal;//where Animal someAnimal
```

or

```
Dog myDog = (Dog) someFriend;//where Friend someFriend
```

I understand this question may require some expertise to answer, so thank you for your help. Please do provide some valuable explanation.

Comment: actually there is cost. so this question is for the experts not beginners: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076555/build-ci-sdlc/java-performance-programming--part-2--the-cost-of-casting.html

Comment: I see you remove your comment that said there was no cost. You should remove your down vote for integrity.

Comment: Could you take a look at my answer and tell me if it answers your question, or if you need anything else clarified? I agree that the downvotes are not necessarily justified, but trying to get them removed is likely to not succeed with extreme efficiency.

Comment: @hexafraction I am thankful for your answer. I am still thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither will be more expensive, if you look at bytecode. I would worry instead about the massive overhead of constructing and throwing `ClassCastExceptions`, which happens *in either case* if the cast fails. At any rate, `instanceof` won't hurt you particularly either, and let you get away with less performance penalty if the cast can't occur.

Here is casting a variable declared as `CharSequence` (an interface) to String:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String a
       2: astore_1
       3: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       6: aload_1
       7: checkcast     #4                  // class java/lang/String
      10: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      13: return
```

And casting a class to a subclass:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class A$B
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method A$B."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      11: aload_1
      12: checkcast     #2                  // class A$B
      15: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      18: return
}
```

Anyway, here's the impact of `instanceof`:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class A$B
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method A$B."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: instanceof    #2                  // class A$B
      12: ifeq          25
      15: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      18: aload_1
      19: checkcast     #2                  // class A$B
      22: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      25: return
```

As you can see it's just an extra bytecode operation (which typically will just check a few elements of the object instance as it exists in memory) and an if-statement branch.